# Kyoto cabinet TreeDB: memory usage grows uncontrollably until database is closed

Tags: c++, memory-management, kyotocabinet

I've been trying to use kyotocabinet TreeDB (MSVC10 build) and stumbled upon a strange memory issue: basically, on each database write, memory usage grows and it doesn't drop until database is closed.

The test code looks like this:

```
size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 1 << 20; // use 1MB-sized records
char* test_block = new char[BLOCK_SIZE]; // allocate record data

TreeDB db;
db.open("test.db")

// add 5000 records
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)
{
    // at each call, process virtual memory usage increases by 1 MB even though i'm not allocating more memory
    // also, as expected, in x86-32 process the whole thing runs out of memory and crashes when iteration counter comes close to 2000
    db.set(&i, sizeof(i), test_block, BLOCK_SIZE);
}

db.close(); // memory usage returns to normal here
delete [] test_block;
```

Of course, I could open/close database when adding each record, but this introduces a huge delay (about 1 sec), which is not acceptable for my task.
Also, this problem doesn't occur in HashDB, but I can't really use HashDB, as I occasionally need sequential access by key.

I've tried altering tuning parameters (tune_page_cache, tune_buckets, tune_page) but with no luck. Could please someone hint at what I'm missing here? I need to store an unpredictable amount of 100KB-10MB sized records and run it on 32-bit system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `db.synchronize()` would help, as it should push cached data out to the filesystem, allowing user memory to free up.  If so, and you need this to happen all the time, call `open` with the optional argument OAUTOSYNC, although this will likely slow you down quite a lot.

Comment: Indeed, call to db.synchronize() provides a solution to the memory problem with a lesser (but still noticeable) performance cost. I finally settled with calling db.synchronize() after every hundred writes, it worked well enough for my problem.